# Creating gRPC server with c#. Return types Task?

Tags: c#, grpc

I created a gRPC server with C#. Quite simple.
What confuses me is that the return types of all message requests are `Tasks`.

From the example Greeting server:

```
public override Task<HelloReply> SayHello(HelloRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
{
    return Task.FromResult(new HelloReply { Message = "Hello " + request.Name });
}
```

I wonder why the return type is not just `HelloReply`. I started creating my own server and continued returning `Task.FromResult` but actually it is not the way Task was meant to be used. So I fear I am missing something (regarding performance?). But on the other side I can not image what there could be wrong. A gRPC server is parallel itself for every request, isn't it?
So I what situations is returning Task useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concurrent (parallel) is different to async (Task etc); using a blocking (non-async) call means that a thread is tied up dedicated to your operation, for the duration of your operation, which is not hugely scalable considering that most *real* services involve external IO (databases, files, etc) - and it is *here* that async adds huge benefits. Threads are expensive and limited - which imposes an artificial throughput limit, which can be avoided via async. Returning something awaitable such as `Task<HelloReply>` or `ValueTask<HelloReply>` is a pre-requisite for *allowing* (but not demanding) things to be async.

If you don't need that (which seems unlikely): use `Task.FromResult`, as you are doing. Or if you're using protobuf-net.Grpc: synchronous methods are supported directly (it basically wraps it very similarly to how you're doing it).

Comment: So the Task that is used let's say for getting data from the database async has a smaller footprint than the Task that handles the rpc request?

Comment: @Klamsi in this context, tasks don't "handle" *anything* - they're placeholders for a result that may be known now, or may be known in the future - nothing more; the footprint isn't huge in any real sense, and when possible: `ValueTask[<T>]` can help reduce even that. Getting data from a database via ADO.NET typically has a **lot** of associated baggage (the ADO.NET API notoriously involves a lot of objects), so: compared to everything else that is going on: a `Task<T>` result is basically nothing. In some contexts (not this) the task overhead *can* matter, and can be optimized with tricks.

Comment: I think I got it thanks. So there is definitely parallelism, but with Task.FromResult a Thread is blocked for the duration of the request while with async it could be reused meanwhile. In summary: It saves memory.

Comment: @Klamsi not memory - threads (if anything it spends a *teeny tiny* amount of memory to *allow* you to do this)

Comment: Isn't threads equivalent to memory?

Comment: @Klamsi not really, no - although threads *do have* a memory cost each (for the stack-space), so *from a certain perspective* you could argue that since using async allows you to handle the same load using fewer threads, you will *also* save a pile of memory associated with their stack overheads. And indeed, the memory cost of threads is *why* you don't just spawn a new thread for each individual request, and let it do whatever it does, then die.

Comment: What if `Task.FromResult` contains a long running call? Will grpc block this thread until I replace the return type to `public override async Task<T>` and use some real async function inside with `await`?

Comment: @Martin if you use `Task.FromResult(SomeSynchronousCode())`, then *your code* has blocked the thread - gRPC didn't get consulted on the matter; but yes, using `async` and `await` would free the thread up *if* the thing you're now awaiting is "true" async, i.e. if there are non-CPU tasks happening (database, network, etc): they are awaited in the async sense

Comment: Ok, but does it really matter if I'm doing "real" async work. What if I'm calling `await MyTask();` and `MyTask` doesn't really do anything asynchronous. i.e `Thread.Sleep(10000);`. Is the thread then still blocked. So this is more a general question.

Comment: Think I got it. As long a Task did not run any asynchronous stuff with the usage of `await` it will run synchronous and is not await able.

Comment: @Martin yes; note that this doesn't necessarily mean you're burning CPU, though - as per your sleep example; but it could lead to thread starvation, especially if you block the pool threads for an extended time